# Marginalized likelihood for multiple iid measurements

Tags: bayesian, likelihood

Consider we have a set of i.i.d. measurements $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ corresponding to the random variabel $X$. Each of these measurements is associated with an additive error, such as $x_i=x+\epsilon_i$. A zero-mean Gaussian PDF is assumed to describe the error, $f_{\epsilon_i}$.

The random variable $X$ follows a normal distribution with uncertain mean $\mu_X$ and standard deviation $\sigma_X$. We want to update using Bayes' rule the parameters $\mu_X$ and $\sigma_X$ using the measurements we have. The marginalized likelihood is then needed. For a single measurement $x_i$, the marginalized likelihood is:

$L_{i}(\mu_X,\sigma_X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X_i|X}(x_{i}|x)f_{X}(x|\mu_X,\sigma_X)\, dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{\epsilon}(x_{i}-x)f_{X}(x|\mu_X,\sigma_X)\, dx$

For multiple measurements $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$, which of the following types is the correct one?

(1) $L(\mu_X,\sigma_X)=\prod_{i=1}^n\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{\epsilon_i}(x_{i}-x)f_{X}(x|\mu_X,\sigma_X)\, dx$

or

(2) $L(\mu_X,\sigma_X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\prod_{i=1}^nf_{\epsilon_i}(x_{i}-x)f_{X}(x|\mu_X,\sigma_X)\, dx$

Comment: Write down the joint distribution of $(x,x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and integrate in $x$.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? The mathematics give me (2), but (1) produces more rational results.